# Synonym for every time achieving optimum result

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Any word for achieve/gain every time optimum result.
few in my mind `perfect`, `10/10`.

Usage: Ninja algorithm always achieves the optimum result.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Aside: an "optimized" result may not mean what you seem to think. Perhaps "optimum" would be better here.

Comment: Thanks, @WeatherVane will edit

Comment: How about "dumb luck"?

Answer (score 0):

- **Accurate**
- **Absolute**

If you are referring to the "perfect" synonyms, you can refer here :

> https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/perfect